# RichTextBox not processing new line/carriage return characters

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio-2008, richtextbox

I seem to be experiencing a very unusual issue with the `RichTextBox` control, programming in C# in Visual Studio 2008.

I'm currently reading the stream of a file that's being written to by the windows console (with output redirection), and I'm reading it into my program (essentially, I'm recreating what's known in the unix world as "tail").

When an array of bytes is read in, I'd like to return to a new line line, and continue reading. However, it seems like my RTB will not respond to new line or carriage return characters. For example, I've tried appending `\n`, `\r\n`, and even `Environment.NewLine` to the string being written, but nothing seems to be working. It just keeps writing across the same line.

Here is the code that seems to be causing trouble:

```
string convertedBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])e.UserState);

outputBox.AppendText(convertedBuffer + "\n");
```

I'm really at a loss here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its probably because you set `outputBox.Multiline` property to false which will  will prevents the control from showing the text in multi-line.

**Edit:** You stated at comment

> the byte array that is being sent was one that I made of set size, 512. I now just changed that to one that actually fits the data being filled in it, and now, all of a sudden, the newline character starts working again

Here is what happened:

The `string` class in C# is an array of `char` start by pointer to the first char in the array and ends by the special "terminal" char `\0`. So when you call `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)` if the buffer size is larger than the string size it will set the all remaining chars of the string to the terminal char in the char array. the array of chars will be something like `some text\0\0\0`, So I am *guessing* that when you add `Environment.NewLine` it will add it to the last index of the char array after last `\0` and then the char array will be `some text\0\0\r\n` and because of the new line is after the terminal it will ignore it.

Comment: That would have been my guess too, unfortunately, the Multiline value is set to true. For more information, when I assign to the Text property rather than adding onto it, it seems that newline characters are fully recognized, as I can see my cursor moving down two lines with I use \n\n. However, in my block of code posted above, it still isn't working.

Comment: @TGP1994: That is odd. I checked it: Added a new `Form` `Form1` and add to it a new `richTextBox1` with its default values. Now at the code evaluate multi add line like `richTextBox1.AppendText("Testing..." + Environment.NewLine); richTextBox1.AppendText("Testing..." + Environment.NewLine);` It will work as expected...

Comment: What about appending a string that was generated from System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()?

Comment: @TGP1994: It is the Same, Change the code to `richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Testing...")) + Environment.NewLine);` and it will still print the same expected results.

Comment: Well, this is strange... the byte array that is being sent was one that I made of set size, 512. I now just changed that to one that actually fits the data being filled in it, and now, all of a sudden, the newline character starts working again. How strange.

Comment: I see.. This probably because the remaining bytes of the string is setted to string terminal value `\0`, So when you add a new line it add it after the last location in `char` array that contains value other than '\0' and still has remaining null terminal charcter in the char array after the new line, so the new line will be ignored.. I will update the answer to include more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just put "\n" or Environment.NewLine separately as follows:

```
outputBox.AppendText(convertedBuffer);
outputBox.AppendText("\n");
```

It works for me... and you don't have to worry about \0

Comment: Thanks for the try, Jakub. :) I'm afraid you're several years late and a correct answer short... In my question I was already appending a newline.

Comment: Hi, yes i was late ad i had the same problem. Unfortunatelly you append new line together with string and this caused me the problem. Once i separate it, it works for me ;-)